# Python (pexpect and pxssh) SSH to Cisco ASA firewall with MOTD Banner

Tags: python, ssh, cisco, pexpect

I'm writing a script in Python and I'm using pxssh and pexpect to get the job done, problem is I can't successfully send any commands and I believe it's due to the MOTD banner. Below is what I have for code so far and below that is what the banner looks like:

```
import pexpect
import getpass
import pxssh
import sys

try:

    s = pxssh.pxssh()

    #this is for input file/lists - host, username, and password
    hostname = ('fw1.aff.tempe')
    username = ('tmarciniak')
    password = ('<password>')
    s.login(hostname, username, password, auto_prompt_reset=False)

    s.logfile = sys.stdout

    #s.expect('***.*') #matching the first characters of the MOTD banner for sending command
    s.sendline('enable') # run a command      
    s.prompt() # match the prompt                                           
    print(s.before)

    #s.prompt() # match the prompt
    # s.sendline('enable') # run a command
    #s.prompt() # match the prompt
    print(s.before) # print everything before the prompt
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```

MOTD Banner and output after successful SSH connection:

```
***********************************************
*                                             *
* This Device is owned by Telesphere Networks *
*                                             *
* Unauthorized Access is Strictly Prohibited  *
*                                             *
*       Telesphere NOC: (800) 680-2203        *
*                                             *
***********************************************
************************************************************************
*
* Name: Amerifirst Financial - Tempe (36714)
*
* Hostname: fw1.aff.tempe
*
* Location: 2151 E Broadway Rd
*           Tempe, AZ 85282
*
* Notes:
*
************************************************************************
Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.
fw1-aff-tempe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that pxssh gets you past the banner and you just need to worry about the prompt. For those that are curious, I did the following:

```
def ssh(hostname, username, password, enable_password):
ssh_session = pxssh.pxssh(maxread=32768, searchwindowsize=1024)

original_prompt = '%s>' % (hostname.replace('.', '-'),) #matching the first line with the prompt as exact as possible
enable_prompt = '%s#' % (hostname.replace('.', '-'),)
ssh_session.login(hostname, username, password, original_prompt=original_prompt, auto_prompt_reset=False)

ssh_session.sendline('enable') # run a command
ssh_session.expect_exact('Password:') #match the response as exact as possible
ssh_session.sendline(enable_password)

#print('%s#' % (hostname.replace('.','-'),))    #not sure what this part does
ssh_session.expect_exact(enable_prompt)

ssh_session.sendline('terminal pager 0')
ssh_session.expect_exact(enable_prompt)
```

I'm logging into Cisco ASA firewalls, which don't accept the "." character as a delimiter in the hostname. I defined a variable that would replace "." with "-", then used that as my "expact_exact" for the expect after a sendline.

On a related note (to Cisco devices) the "terminal pager 0" is for modifying the pager buffer for that specific session to 0; which causes any output to all be shown at once.